# i am trying to install matplotlib but am facing the below shown errors after installing matplotlib.can anyone help me

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Syamu\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\Lib1mpl.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\Syamu\Syam\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\Syamu\Syam\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "C:\Users\Syamu\Syam\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 57, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, _cm, cbook, scale
  File "C:\Users\Syamu\Syam\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\scale.py", line 22, in <module>
    from matplotlib.ticker import (
  File "C:\Users\Syamu\Syam\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 143, in <module>
    from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
  File "C:\Users\Syamu\Syam\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 49, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: The specified module could not be found.
```

TO resolve i did, Firstly i created another virtual project with other name for the purpose of libraries.

Secondly, in terminal i uninstalled matplotlib and again installed using pip3, but failed again.

Then, i tried in several ways to clear this from interent , but unable to work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What version of matplotlib are you trying to install?